# extended base interface applied to a class

Tags: typescript

I am having trouble assigning an extended interface to a class.

I add a minimal example below (and playground at the end of the post):

```
interface A {
    hello:string
}

interface Extension extends A {
    bye:string
}

class Greeting implements Extension {
    constructor(){
        this.hello="hi"
        this.bye= "bye"
    }
}
```

The error is: `Property 'hello' does not exist on type 'Greeting'.` Between other errors.

I understand this is because there is no type definition, but why would it be if I am implementing this interface already? Is there any better way to do this without basically repeating the definition of `Extension` interface ?

To me the way it is written makes sense, but I just can't really get how this should be properly done. Can you help me?

### [TSPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm%20QCwgBsiB7ALgGcwpQBzLAXyy1ElkRQCFkIAPSCAAmlNJhx4ARgE8IVGvSYsEROJVEBxKBAhh6yYAFsADkQiGI4UT2x5kCUiGpQArgjCkoACgCUtu3hg%20MCUAHSEJKQAvABEwTESAchBIaEyEFHIMekJdsyMQA)

Answer (score 0):

Use `class`'es instead of `interface`'s, because the latter are just type, they do not do anything at runtime:

```
class A {
    hello: string
}

class B extends A {
    bye: string
}

class Greeting extends B {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.hello = "hi"
        this.bye = "bye"
    }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XQBYFMQgPYC5oIAXAJwEsA7AcyQF8klRIYAhaTAD2M0oBMY8ZGmgAjAJ6ZCJCjXqNmUaAHFSmTMSrUO3XgOjthaYLkoyArsGK5SACgCUiFCLQRzAB0x37zl9GLo5BAAdFg4uNAAvNAARIExvi4BQcESmFGxaQkiDHRAA)

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to me to define empty classes, why isn't there a good solution for this?

Comment: It is a common practice to gather shared members/behaviour through classes that you may never use as-is, but only extend. You can make them `abstract` if they are really useless before they are extended.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should solve the issue:

```
...
class Greeting implements Extension {
    // initialize the class property
    public hello;
    public bye;
    constructor(){
        this.hello="hi"
        this.bye= "bye"
    }
}
```

Comment: well yes but it defeats the purpose to some extent, as I am repeating all of it